# Why does Typescript allows "import" in CommonJS modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, es6-modules, commonjs

I am trying to get a handle on Typescript's [module system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html), but even after reading carefully the documentation, I couldn't understand the following behavior :

**Setup**

`Child.ts`

```
export const child = "Child";
```

`Parent.ts`

```ts
import { child } from "./Child";
console.log(child);
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "node16",
  "esModuleInterop": true, // No impact whether true of false
```

and my `package.json` doesn't have `"type":"module"`

**Question**

After reading Typescript's [Module format detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#module-format-detection), I expected that : since I don't have `"type":"module"` in my `package.json`, TypeScript would treat my `Parent.ts` and `Child.ts` as `CommonJS` modules, thus Typescript should give me an error on `import` and advice me to use `require()`.

However, this is not the case. Typescript is allowing me to use `import` in a `CommonJS` file.

What did I miss? Is there a config in my `tsconfig.json` that causes this? Thank you for your help

**Edit**
Maybe Typescript natively allow ESM modules for its own `.ts` files and module resolution. However, I undertand that ESM modules requires the extension for relative paths. If true, Typescript should throw an error for `import { child } from "./Child";` and require `import { child } from "./Child.ts";`. But this is not the case

Comment: This just change way how output import looks, not how its used in typescript

Comment: @Wraithy you're right for `tsconfig` `module` config. However, I still don't undertand Typescript own module resolution. (I added an additional section to my question). There may also a be a crucial point that I'm missing or that my understanding of modules is wrong.

Comment: Is it a commonjs file or a typescript file? You are writing typescript, not js. Add type module and see what happens.